# How to add Custom Validation Error in FloatField forms Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Ive tried to make my custom message error if no inputs given, but its always showing the default message "Please fill out this field!"
I have floatfield forms that looks like this

*forms.py*

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    RadioSelectDayaTorsi = forms.ChoiceField(label = "Pilih Input" ,choices=(('D','Daya'), ('T','Torsi')),
                                             initial='D', widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    P = forms.FloatField(label="Daya ",
                            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'kW'}))
    n = forms.FloatField(label="Kecepatan Putar ",
                            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'rpm'}))
    T = forms.FloatField(label="Torsi ",
                            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'N-mm'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        RadioSelectDayaTorsi = cleaned_data.get("RadioSelectDayaTorsi")
        P = cleaned_data.get("P")
        n = cleaned_data.get("n")
        T = cleaned_data.get("T")
        if RadioSelectDayaTorsi == 'D':
            if not P:
                self.add_error('P', 'TEST')
            if not n:
                self.add_error('n', 'Kecepatan putar harus diisi')
        elif RadioSelectDayaTorsi == 'T':
            if not T:
                self.add_error('T', 'Torsi harus diisi')
        return cleaned_data
```

*views.py*

```
def input(request):
    return render(request, "shaft/input.html", {
        "form": MyForm(),
    })

def output(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        RadioSelectDayaTorsi = cleaned_data.get("RadioSelectDayaTorsi")
        P = cleaned_data.get("P")
        n = cleaned_data.get("n")
        T = cleaned_data.get("T")
```

Tried with

```
if RadioSelectDayaTorsi == 'D':
            if not P:
                raise forms.ValidationError('TESTING')
```

also if P == "":
still no works

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Maybe your service didn't get to the conditions part of code?

Comment: Field-specific clean methods are called first, before the catchall `clean()` method.  That is where the error message is assigned.

Comment: You can also add error messages using `self.add_error()`.

Comment: Is that Form by any chance invoked on a Model with fields that have the `required=True`? Or is this Form not related to any Model? Because usually your Error-Message is coming up when at some point you declare that that field is required!

Answer (score 0):

Find the reason for your error [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#required):

> By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you
> pass an empty value – either None or the empty string ("") – then
> clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:

> To specify that a field is not required, pass required=False to the
> Field constructor:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
[...]
    P = forms.FloatField(label="Daya ", required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'kW'}))
```

Now technically it is allowed to **not** have any input at all. Therefore you **have to** implement your own "check" for an empty value. This comes along with the advantage that you can specify the error message.

```py
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
```

The part of your code above is the part where you call the default `clean()` method of the form I guess. And the default `clean()` method gives you your `cleaned_data` but also recognizes: Oh, there is no userinput despite the developer did not put `required=False`! and complains about it with seen error.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default required field validation error message in following ways.

**1. By specifying the invalid key value in `error_messages` argument in the `Form.FloatField()` itself.**

```
P = forms.FloatField(
       required= True,
       #other details you wish to add
       error_messages={'invalid':'custom error message'}
    )
```

2. **By specifying the same in the widget attribute**

   `P = forms.FloatField(widgets={ error_messages={'invalid':'custom error message'}})`
3. Or use bulid-in validators https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/